# Should I change my password if I see an iOS popup that someone tried to login from an unrecognized city?

Tags: ios, security, apple-id, password

An iOS a popup just occurred that says someone tried to login from a city I do not recognize. In the past, I have changed my password when this has happened - but despite using a unique, multi-character password - these popups have occurred at least half-a-dozen times.

Posts from Apple such as referenced on [this SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338276/someone-in-china-tried-to-log-into-my-appleid-account-what-should-i-do) mention that you should refuse requests you do not recognize. They also say you should change your password frequently - but what they don’t mention is whether it is very important to change your password *every* time.

Do these two-factor pop-ups only occur when someone has guessed your password? If you simply refuse the two-factor approval - does the “bot” or whatever hack you still know your password? And does that mean you should change your password *every time* this happpens because someone was able to figure it out? Or is there another interpretation and the account is actually safe by just declining their login?

Comment: I think that the key word here is *tried.* If they had actually logged in you would get an email to that effect, assuming OP is relaying the message accurately then they did not get in, they only **TRIED** to get in.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of valid reasons why this could happen:

- You're using a VPN service that is causing *you* to show up in a different city
- You're being incorrectly geolocated to another city broadly within your region of the world.

Aside from that though (and assuming it's not a phishing message you see), it seems that someone is getting your password, and not only should you be changing it, but also trying to figure out whether you've got a keylogger, are getting phished, etc.